# preg_replace is not working with special chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-greedy, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to fix some misserialized data with a function from stackoverflow answers. What I realized is that some special chars is breaking the pattern. Is there any way to fix this ?

string:

```
s:4:"text";s:317:"<div style="text-align:center">
<img src="http://dev-xxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.net/mirza/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2014/09/footer-logo1.png" alt="yyyyyyyy template" />
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px"><span style="font-size:11px;color:#fff">COPYRIGHT ALL RIGHTS RESERVED � 2014</span></div>

";s:6:"filter";b:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";
```

function:

```
    $row_sub["option_value"] = preg_replace_callback ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', function($match) {

        echo " - ".$match[1]." -
        ";
        echo " - ".strlen($match[2])." - <br />
        ";
        echo " - ".$match[2]." - <br />
        ";

        return ($match[1] == strlen($match[2])) ? $match[0] : 's:' . strlen($match[2]) . ':"' . $match[2] . '";';
    },$row_sub["option_value"]);
```

output :

```
                     - 4 -
                     - 4 - <br />
                     - text - <br />
                     - 6 -
                     - 6 - <br />
                     - filter - <br />
                     - 12 -
                     - 12 - <br />
                     - _multiwidget - <br />
```

Expected output:

```
                 - 4 -
                 - 4 - <br />
                 - text - <br />
                 - 317 - 
                 - 325 - <br />
                 -  <div style="text-align:center">
                            <img src="http://dev-xxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.net/mirza/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2014/09/footer-logo1.png" alt="yyyyyyyy template" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px"><span style="font-size:11px;color:#fff">COPYRIGHT ALL RIGHTS RESERVED � 2014</span></div> - <br /> 
                 - 6 -
                 - 6 - <br />
                 - filter - <br />
                 - 12 -
                 - 12 - <br />
                 - _multiwidget - <br />
```

As you can see the part with html tags are missing. Probably because of the copyright sign.

How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: could you add the output that you would like to have?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro added.

Answer (score 0):

it wasn't a special char issue.

using proper delimeters solved the problem:

```
preg_replace_callback ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!smi',
```

Comment: Do you mean the `//s` modifier  (dot-all) is all that was needed.?

Comment: Then you don't need the multi-line nor case insensitive modifiers. But I can understand throwing the kitchen sink at it.